# I have a snake game that runs on c code and i want to see if there are ways to make it more accessable on different compilers

Tags: c, portability

For a class project, my group made a snake game that runs on C code, but it uses libraries that aren't standard. Is there any way to make the game run on more platforms besides the one I'm using, which is Code::Blocks?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void setup();       //Initialized all the functions
void draw();
void input();
void updateGame();
void logic();
void clearScreen();
void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void newHighscore();

int gameover = 0;       //Initialized all the variables
int x, y;
int fruitx, fruity;
int score;
int height, width;
char mode[10];
int snakeLength = 1;
int* snakeBody;
int dx = 0;
int dy = 0;
int highScore;

void setup() {  // Setup Function used to get Map Size and snake head location
    printf("Enter Map Size (Small, Medium, Large): ");
    scanf("%s", mode);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    mode[i] = tolower(mode[i]);  //tolower makes all the inputs scanned into lower case so any input, "LARGE", or "large" will work
    }
    if (strcmp(mode, "small") == 0) {
        height = 10;
        width = 20;
    } else if (strcmp(mode, "medium") == 0) {
        height = 20;
        width = 40;
    } else if (strcmp(mode, "large") == 0) {
        height = 30;
        width = 60;
    }
    x = height / 2;
    y = width / 2;
    score = 0;
    snakeBody = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2 * (height * width)); //creates dynamic array to hold the x and y coordinates of
    snakeBody[0] = x;                                       //the x and y of the snake body ex: [segment 1: 1, segment 1: 1, segment 2: 1, segment 2: 2]
    snakeBody[1] = y;                                       //                                              x,            y,            x,            y

    srand(time(NULL));
    do {
        fruitx = rand() % (height - 2) + 1;  //do while loop that gets a random
        fruity = rand() % (width - 2) + 1;   //x and y coordinates for a fruit
    } while (fruitx == x || fruity == y);    //if the x and y equals the snake head then it tries again
}

void draw() {  //Draw function to draw all the borders, snake parts, fruits, and empty space
    gotoxy(1, 1);   //sends cursor to the coordinates 1,1

    printf("\033[?25l"); // ASCII to hide the cursor so when its printing the game it is not flashing across the screen

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == height - 1 || j == 0 || j == width - 1){
                printf("#");
            } else if (i == fruitx && j == fruity) {
                printf("b");                                //For loop that draws different aspects determined by different conditions
            } else if (i == x && j == y) {
                    printf("O");
            } else {
                int isBody = 0;
                for (int k = 1; k < snakeLength; k++) {
                    if (i == snakeBody[2 * k] && j == snakeBody[2 * k + 1]) {
                        printf("0");
                        isBody = 1;
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (!isBody) {
                printf(" ");
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    if (strcmp(mode, "small") == 0) {                   //separate print statements for each map size to
    printf("Score: %d Press X to Quit\n", score);       //make appearance of score and quit statment fit cleanly
    }
    if (strcmp(mode, "medium") == 0) {
    printf("Score: %d                 Press X to Quit\n", score);
    }
    if (strcmp(mode, "large") == 0) {
    printf("Score: %d                                     Press X to Quit\n", score);
    }
    fflush(stdout); //removes buffer so it immediately shows the printing


}

void input() {      //Input Function to get keyboard hits
    if (kbhit()) {
        switch (getch()) {
            case 'w':       //When "w" is clicked it sets x coordinate to go -1
                if (dx != 1) {  //if statement so only when your not going down
                    dx = -1;    //are you allowed to go up
                    dy = 0;     //applies to all directions where you cannot go opposite the direction currently going
                }
                break;
            case 's':       //When "s" is clicked it sets x coordinate to go +1
                if (dx != -1) {
                    dx = 1;
                    dy = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 'a':       //When "a" is clicked it sets y coordinate to go -1
                if (dy != 1) {
                    dx = 0;
                    dy = -1;
                }
                break;
            case 'd':       //When "d" is clicked it sets y coordinate to go +1
                if (dy != -1) {
                    dx = 0;
                    dy = 1;
                }
                break;
            case 'x':       //When "x" is clicked it sets game over to 1 and ends the game
                gameover = 1;
                break;
        }
    }
}

void updateGame() { //Update Game Function
    input(); //Calls input function to update direction

    // Move the head
    x += dx;
    y += dy;

    // Continuously make body segments take the place of the earlier body part. This makes the snake look like it is following the snake head
    for (int k = snakeLength - 1; k > 0; k--) {
        snakeBody[2 * k] = snakeBody[2 * (k - 1)];
        snakeBody[2 * k + 1] = snakeBody[2 * (k - 1) + 1];
    }

    // Update the position of the first body segment
    snakeBody[0] = x;
    snakeBody[1] = y;

}
int FruitBody (int fruitx, int fruity) { //Function so the fruit does not spawn in a body segment
    for (int k = 0; k < snakeLength; k++) {
    if (fruitx == snakeBody[2 * k] && fruity == snakeBody[2 * k + 1]) {
        return 1;
        }
    }
return 0;
}

void logic() {
    if (x == 0 || x == height - 1 || y == 0 || y == width - 1) {
        gameover = 1; // Snake hits the wall
        return;
    }
    for (int k = 1; k < snakeLength; k++){
    if (x == snakeBody[2 * k] && y == snakeBody[2 * k + 1]) {
        gameover = 1; // Snake hits its own body
        return;
        }
    }

    if (x == fruitx && y == fruity) {
        score++; //When the snake eats a fruit it increases body and score
        snakeLength++;

        do {  //Fruit spawn that happens when fruit is eaten, includes the function FruitBody so it does not spawn in snake body
            fruitx = rand() % (height - 2) + 1;
            fruity = rand() % (width - 2) + 1;
        } while (fruitx == x || fruity == y || FruitBody(fruitx, fruity));
    }
}

void clearScreen() {
    system("cls"); //Used to clear the screen after setup
}

void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
    printf("\033[%d;%dH", x, y); //goto function for moving cursor to the x and y coordinates. (ASCII for cursor)
}

void newHighscore () { // High Score File to store the information on the high score as well as read and write a new score if it is higher than previous
    FILE * highscore = fopen ("highscore.txt", "r");
    fscanf(highscore, "%d", &highScore);
    fclose(highscore);
    if (score > highScore) {
    highscore = fopen ("highscore.txt", "w");
    fprintf (highscore, "%d", score);
    fclose(highscore);
    highscore = fopen ("highscore.txt", "r");
    fscanf(highscore, "%d", &highScore);
    }


    fclose(highscore);
}

int main() { //Main used to call all the functions
    char playAgain; //character for playing again
    do {
    setup(); //do while loop so it loops the game if play again is chosen
    clearScreen();

    while (!gameover) {  //while loop that runs as long as game over is not equal to 1
        draw();  //First run draw function
        logic(); //Then check logic
        updateGame(); //Then update game accordingly
        usleep(100000); // Used to slow down the process so it is playable
    }

    newHighscore(); //Calls newHighscore function to check if there is a new high score

    printf("\033[?25h"); //Reveals cursor so you can see where you are writing to

    clearScreen(); //Clears screen of Game

    printf("Game Over! Final Score: %d  High Score: %d\n", score, highScore);
    printf("  Play Again? (y/n)   "); //Prints the GAMEOVER statement and asks if you want to play again
    scanf(" %c", &playAgain);
    playAgain = tolower(playAgain); //tolower makes all the inputs scanned into lower case so any input, "Y", or "y" will work

    clearScreen(); //Clears the print statements

    gameover = 0; //Resets all the variables that were changed in previous game
    snakeLength = 1;
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;

    } while (playAgain == 'y'); //Do while loop so if they want to play again it goes through the whole game main function

    free(snakeBody); //If they do not want to play the game anymore then it frees the snakebody memory

    return 0;
}
```

This is the code so far.

I am new to coding so im not sure on what exactly I should change to make it more accessable. I like some of the code i have now like for kbhit and getting the inputs for direction but conio.h isnt standard and wont work on unix systems

Comment: You use `<conio.h>` which I thought was only available on Windows. It's a non-standard header that's really a left-over from the DOS days. But then you also include `<unistd.h>` which is a POSIX-specific header file and shouldn't be available on Windows. So that kind of confuses me. If you want a potable console program, that can work on either Windows or Linux, there are libraries that can help you with that. One such library is ncurses which originally comes from the Unix world (i.e. POSIX) but have been ported to Windows as well.

Comment: On another note, you should really refactor (update) your code to get rid of all the global variables. Global variables is a bad habit. Use function arguments to pass data to functions instead. Possibly in the form of structures.